# Pythonic way of finding duplicate maps in a list while ignoring certain keys, and combining the duplicate maps to make a new list

Tags: python, list, dictionary, duplicates, ipython

I want to write a code which takes the following inputs:

```
list (list of maps)
request_keys (list of strings)
operation (add,substract,multiply,concat)
```

The code would look at the list for the maps having the same value for all keys except the keys given in request_keys. Upon finding two maps for which the value in the search keys match, the code would do the operation (add,multiple,substract,concat) on the two maps and combine them into one map. This combination map would basically replace the other two maps.

i have written the following peice of code to do this. The code only does add operation. It can be extended to make the other operations

```
In [83]: list
Out[83]: 
[{'a': 2, 'b': 3, 'c': 10},
 {'a': 2, 'b': 3, 'c': 3},
 {'a': 2, 'b': 4, 'c': 4},
 {'a': 2, 'b': 3, 'c': 2},
 {'a': 2, 'b': 3, 'c': 3}]

In [84]: %cpaste
Pasting code; enter '--' alone on the line to stop or use Ctrl-D.
:def func(list,request_keys):
:    new_list = []
:    found_indexes = []
:    for i in range(0,len(list)):
:        new_item = list[i]
:        if i in found_indexes:
:            continue
:        for j in range(0,len(list)):
:            if i != j and {k: v for k,v in list[i].iteritems() if k not in request_keys} == {k: v for k,v in list[j].iteritems() if k not in request_keys}:
:                found_indexes.append(j)
:                for request_key in request_keys:
:                    new_item[request_key] += list[j][request_key]
:        new_list.append(new_item)
:    return new_list
:--

In [85]: func(list,['c'])
Out[85]: [{'a': 2, 'b': 3, 'c': 18}, {'a': 2, 'b': 4, 'c': 4}]

In [86]:
```

What i want to know is, is there a faster, more memory efficient, cleaner and a more pythonic way of doing the same?

Thank you

Comment: for i in range(len(list)) can be improved. See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OSGv2VnC0go

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You manually generate all the combinations and then compare each of those combinations. This is pretty wasteful. Instead, I suggest grouping the dictionaries in another dictionary by their matching keys, then adding the "same" dictionaries. Also, you forgot the `operator` parameter.

```
import collections, operator, functools
def func(lst, request_keys, op=operator.add):
    matching_dicts = collections.defaultdict(list)
    for d in lst:
        key = tuple(sorted(((k, d[k]) for k in d if k not in request_keys)))
        matching_dicts[key].append(d)

    for group in matching_dicts.values():
        merged = dict(group[0])
        merged.update({key: functools.reduce(op, (g[key] for g in group)) 
                       for key in request_keys})
        yield merged
```

What this does: First, it creates a dictionary, mapping the key-value pairs that have to be equal for two dictionaries to match to all those dictionaries that have those key-value pairs. Then it iterates the dicts from those groups, using one of that group as a prototype and updating it with the sum (or product, or whatever, depending on the operator) of the all the dicts in that group for the `required_keys`.

Note that this returns a generator. If you want a list, just call it like `list(func(...))`, or accumulate the `merged` dicts in a list and return that list.

Comment: Can you please explain the code. It would help a lot. I tried to use it with the input i have given in the code above. The function returns a generator. I tried to iterate over the generator and print by doing: for i in func(list,['c']):    print i. When i do this, i get a "TypeError: first argument must be callable". Can you please edit the reply with the input given above and show how the output is achieved?

Comment: Maybe the problem is because you names your list like the builtin `list` function, thus shadowing that function. Try giving it another name.

Answer (score 1):

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

def mergeDic(inputData, request_keys):
    keys = inputData[0].keys()
    comparedKeys = [item for item in keys if item not in request_keys]
    grouper = itemgetter(*comparedKeys)
    result = []
    for key, grp in groupby(sorted(inputData, key = grouper), grouper):
        temp_dict = dict(zip(comparedKeys, key))
        for request_key in request_keys:
            temp_dict[request_key] = sum(item[request_key] for item in grp)
        result.append(temp_dict)
    return result

inputData = [{'a': 2, 'b': 3, 'c': 10},
 {'a': 2, 'b': 3, 'c': 3},
 {'a': 2, 'b': 4, 'c': 4},
 {'a': 2, 'b': 3, 'c': 2},
 {'a': 2, 'b': 3, 'c': 3}]
from pprint import pprint
pprint(mergeDic(inputData,['c']))
```